# I'm looking for some deep learning super resolution code

Tags: video

Is there any publicly available code that uses deep learning to employ super-resolution techniques to improve the quality of video clips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well models for these things are easy and widely available. https://github.com/msmsajjadi/FRVSR is an example. You can also write one yourself. Tutorials to common machine learning frameworks are abundant and easy to follow.